# Counting grouped rows only shows 1

Tags: mysql, sql

here's my query.

```
$qry = "SELECT *
        FROM users 
        GROUP BY source
        HAVING COUNT(source) >= 2
        ORDER BY COUNT(source) 
        DESC LIMIT 0, 3";

mysql_set_charset("UTF8");
$result = @mysql_query($qry);
if($result === FALSE) {
    die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
}

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo $row['source'];
echo count($row['source']);
echo "<br>";
}
```

i dont know why it only displays 1, but that is just 1 column with a lot of similar values, i would like to query them and show how many values are there, for example apple is in the column for 10 times, it would display apple 10.

i dont know why my query wont work, and just displays 1, please help, thank you. :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to select count too

```
    $qry = "SELECT source,   COUNT(source)
    FROM users 
    GROUP BY source
    HAVING COUNT(source) >= 2
    ORDER BY COUNT(source) 
    DESC LIMIT 0, 3"
```